# Viewpager2 dependency causes crash at launch

Tags: android-studio, android-appcompat, android-viewpager2

Adding the Viewpager2 dependency makes my app crash at launch.

When my dependencies looks like this, everything works exactly as it should.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation "com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0"
    implementation 'com.zsoltsafrany:needle:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:javase:3.3.0'
}
```

But as soon as I uncomment `implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'`, my app crashes instantly.

```
2019-12-18 17:51:16.134 7012-7012/com.example.[PROJECT] D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-12-18 17:51:16.135 7012-7012/com.example.[PROJECT] E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.[PROJECT], PID: 7012
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.[PROJECT]/com.example.[PROJECT].Login}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: true, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: true, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:670)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.[PROJECT].Login.onCreate(Login.java:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I'm using Android Studio 3.5.1 and Gradle 5.4.1, if that matters at all. I can't figure out why adding this dependency would make my theme suddenly break, especially since my theme is as barebones as they come.

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="[PROJECT]Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: can you please share the theme

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod Added my app theme